# Get the blood type of each generation by recursion

Tags: c, recursion

I am trying to get the blood type of each generation (parents and grandparents) by randomly assigning the child alleles. I ended up hardcoding it. Is there any way to revise the code by using recursion so I won't be hardcoding? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
> // Create a new individual with `generations` person
> *create_family(int generations) {
>     // create a new person and use it potentially to get the ancestors
>     person *p = malloc(sizeof(person));
>     p -> alleles[0] = random_allele();
>     p -> alleles[1] = random_allele();
>     // Recursively create blood type histories for parents
>     person *parent1 = malloc(sizeof(person));
>     person *parent2 = malloc(sizeof(person));
>     person *grandparent1 = malloc(sizeof(person));
>     person *grandparent2 = malloc(sizeof(person));
>     person *grandparent3 = malloc(sizeof(person));
>     person *grandparent4 = malloc(sizeof(person));
>             
>     // update the new person's parents
>     if ((parent1 == NULL) || (parent2 == NULL) || (grandparent1 == NULL) || (grandparent2 == NULL) || (grandparent3 == NULL) ||
> (grandparent4 == NULL))
>     {
>         return false;
>     }
>     // Generation with parent data
>     if (generations > 1)
>     {
>         if (p == NULL)
>         {
>             return false;
>         }
>         if (p != NULL)
>         {
>             //set parent[0] equals the recursive call
>             p -> parents[0] = parent1;
>             p -> parents[1] = parent2;
>             
>             parent1 -> parents[0] = grandparent1;
>             parent1 -> parents[1] = grandparent2;
>             parent2 -> parents[0] = grandparent3;
>             parent2 -> parents[1] = grandparent4;
> 
>             // Randomly assign child alleles based on parents
>             parent1 -> alleles[0] = p -> alleles[0];
>             parent1 -> alleles[1] = random_allele();
>             parent2 -> alleles[0] = p -> alleles[1];
>             parent2 -> alleles[1] = random_allele();
>             
>             grandparent1 -> alleles[0] = parent1 -> alleles[0];
>             grandparent1 -> alleles[1] = random_allele();
>             grandparent2 -> alleles[0] = parent1 -> alleles[1];
>             grandparent2 -> alleles[1] = random_allele();
>             grandparent3 -> alleles[0] = parent2 -> alleles[0];
>             grandparent3 -> alleles[1] = random_allele();
>             grandparent4 -> alleles[0] = parent2 -> alleles[1];
>             grandparent4 -> alleles[1] = random_allele();
>         }
>     }
> }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide sample inputs and expected outputs. Too much boilerplate is missing--what's `random_allele()` do? See [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: An MRE is compilable, which is a conflict with starting each line with a `>`. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help on how to suitably format code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good case for recursion. Updated to pass the child's allele to the parent

```
// Call this function
person * create_family(int generations)
{
    return create_family_recursive(generations, random_allele());
}

// This function only gets called by the other
person * create_family_recursive(int generations, allele *parent_allele)
{
    if (generations == 0) return NULL;  // End recursion

    // Create a person
    person * child = malloc(sizeof(person));
    child->alleles[0] = parent_allele;
    child->alleles[1] = random_allele();

    // Create 2 parents (and all generations prior)
    child->parents[0] = create_family(generations - 1, child->alleles[0]);
    child->parents[1] = create_family(generations - 1, child->alleles[1]);

    return child;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried but the line of re-assign doesn't work.. I changed it this, but it doesn't work correctly for the grandparents' generation. Any thoughts? 
            ```p -> parents[0] -> alleles[0] = p -> alleles[0];``` <br/>
            ```p -> parents[0] -> alleles[1] = random_allele();``` <br/>
            ```p -> parents[1] -> alleles[0] = p -> alleles[1];``` <br/>
            ```p -> parents[1] -> alleles[1] = random_allele();``` <br/>

Comment: @Snowyaya Ok. I have modified it to (hopefully) produce the desired result.